# Will the spacetime around a rotating spherical massive body change in time or not?

Tags: general-relativity, frame-dragging

The spacetime around a rotating massive body is distorted (in addition to the distortion caused by the body's gravity) by [frame dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging). My question is simple. Is this distortion around a massive rotating body (at constant angular velocity) changing in time, i.e. gets the spacetime "winded up" more and more or isn't it? If so can we measure the difference in the time of how long two equal massive spherical bodies are already rotating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the spacetime around a rotating massive body does not get more wound up as time passes.

For example, the Kerr metric for a rotating black hole is **stationary**. Loosely speaking, this means that it's invariant under time-translations. Technically, it means that the spacetime has a timelike Killing vector field. The metric can be expressed in a coordinate system where all of its components are independent of the "time" coordinate.

More generally, the spacetime outside an isolated massive rotating body has this same property if the stress-energy tensor is independent of time. The Einstein field equation depends on matter only via the stress-energy tensor. The metric (in a standard coordinate system) will have a cross-term of the form $dt\,d\phi$, where $t$ is the "time" coordinate and $\phi$ is the angular coordinate around the axis of symmetry, and this term gives rise to the frame-dragging effect. But the metric itself is independent of $t$ (in a suitable coordinate system), so the spacetime does not get wound up. It's stationary.

Answer (score 2):

No, frame-dragging doesn’t cause spacetime to get wound up, so you can’t tell how long a body has been rotating. If the body is spherically symmetric, its metric doesn’t even change with time even though the body is rotating. If the body isn’t spherically symmetric, it radiates gravitational waves but there’s no windup.